# Doctrine2 generate entities with setters and getters

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I've successfully installed and used doctrine according to this article: [Getting started with Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html).

Now I want to reverse engineer an existing database. I tried running the following command:

```
php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database annotation entity/generated
```

and that generated entity files with the correct annotations. However, I want to generate the setters and getters instead of having to code them myself.

Many people are referring to this article: [How to generate Entities from an Existing Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html). The first command in the article is:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
```

I cannot find the app folder nor the console file from the installation of Symfony and Doctrine. My composer.json file contents are:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
    }
}
```

I got this from the Getting Started with Doctrine article. Am I missing a dependency in my composer.json file? Where can I find app/console?

EDIT 1:

Paul Andrieux, I added "symfony/framework-standard-edition": "2.5.*" to my composer.json file. Now I have a folder vendor/framework-standard-edition. This contains an app folder which contains the console file. However, I get an error for because the "console" script is attempting "require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap.php.cache'" and the bootstrap.php.cache does not exist. What should this file contain? do I need to create it myself? What other steps should I take after creating or acquiring this file?

Comment: FYI: If you followed the "Getting Started" with Doctrine documentation then you didn't install Symfony. Symfony uses Doctrine but Doctrine does not use Symfony.

Comment: generating geters and seters is a thing every IDE can without sweating.

Answer (score 1):

I found way to generate Getter & Setters just use Doctrine ORM.

you should use `orm:convert-mapping` generate XML mapping file then use `orm:generate-entities` generate XML to PHP class

```
orm:convert-mapping [--filter FILTER] [-f|--force] [--from-database] [--extend [EXTEND]] [--num-spaces [NUM-SPACES]] [--namespace [NAMESPACE]] [--] <to-type> <dest-path>
orm:generate-entities [--filter FILTER] [--generate-annotations [GENERATE-ANNOTATIONS]] [--generate-methods [GENERATE-METHODS]] [--regenerate-entities [REGENERATE-ENTITIES]] [--update-entities [UPDATE-ENTITIES]] [--extend EXTEND] [--num-spaces NUM-SPACES] [--no-backup] [--] <dest-path>
```

A. My `composer.json` (I'm use doctrine 2.5.*)

```
...
"require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5"
},
...
```

B. Config cli tools

My `cli-config.php`

NOTE: use method `createXMLMetadataConfiguration` NOT `createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration`

```
<?php
$db = [
    // ...
];
$paths = [ __DIR__ . '/../Model/'];

// this place should use function Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration
$config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration($paths, false);
$entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($db, $config);
return \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

C. generate XML

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping -f --namespace='Model\' --from-database xml app/Model
```

path `app/Model` must match you `paths` when set in file `cli-config.php`

D. generate PHP class

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations="true"  app/
```

this will generate the right content and right namespace to what you want

Answer (score 0):

According to your composer.json file, you didn't install symfony2, only it's yaml component.

Just follow this guide if you want to install symfony2 full stack: http://symfony.com/get-started